# Bash script is not terminated with Ctrl+C

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals

My script cannot be terminated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key. It is an error.

Please explain how to modify my script to make it terminable by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  paplay /usr/share/sounds/phone.wav
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you catch SIGINT in the parent shell and exit the shell, it brings down paplay too:

```
trap exit SIGINT;
while true; do paplay  /usr/share/sounds/phone.wav ; done
```

It looks like `paplay` blocks the INT signal and that affects that prevents the parent shell from running its default handler.

Installing a handler in the parent shell in which you reset the handler and reraise the signal probably solves it in a better way:

```
trap 'trap - SIGINT; kill -SIGINT $$' SIGINT; 
while :; do paplay  /usr/share/sounds/linuxmint-login.wav ; done
```

(With the `exit` approach the launcher process thinks its child exited voluntarily whereas with the second approach it looks like the script was killed with `SIGINT` which it was).

Answer (score 0):

The question is actually about `paplay`, which may be blocking signals, or (as hinted in the [Arch Wiki](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/PulseAudio)), may be simply too busy.

You could make the script easier to stop by putting a `sleep 1` in the loop.